# ¿Como generar automáticamente Getters y Setter en Android Studio con Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, studio

Se que el acceso rápido es alt+insertar en Windows pero al hacerlo somo me aparece esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto es dentro de un Kotlin Class

Answer (score 0):

**En una clase `Kotlin` usando `Android Studio` ya no podràs obtener las opciones para crear getter y setter mediante <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ins</kbd>** , ya que se definen y obtienen de forma diferente los valores de las propiedades en el objeto.

Ejemplo:

```
 class Persona {
    var nombre: String = "defaultvalue"
        get() = field                     // getter
        set(value) { field = value }      // setter
}
```

Para obtener el valor instancias y obtienes la propiedad nombre de la siguiente forma:

```
 val p = Persona()
 println(p.nombre) //getter
```

Para definir el valor instancias y asignas el valor a la propiedad de la siguiente forma:

```
  val p = Persona()
  p.nombre = "Jorgesys"  //setter
```